# How to write an img element with several double quotation marks when using "append"

Tags: jquery, path, append, double-quotes

I am trying to use "append" to add an img element on my html. But the img tag includes several double quotation marks. Is this a right way to use "append"? Or is there something wrong? Thank you for taking your time.

```
$($(".item .label")[0]).append(" <img src="images/king.png" alt="king"> ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS uses both `'` and `"` to delimit strings. Therefore, you can alternate to avoid having to escape quotes within a string.

You also don't need to double-wrap the jQuery object as you can use `eq()` to get the jQuery object by index instead of the Element object. Try this:

```
$(".item .label").eq(i).append('<img src="images/king.png" alt="king" />');
```

Alternatively (now that you edited the `i` to a fixed `0` value), you can just use the `:first` selector:

```
$(".item .label:first").append('<img src="images/king.png" alt="king" />');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It perfectly worked!

Comment: I dont know why, but it says i need to wait for two more minutes until I am able to accept your answer... give me two more minutes!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Life Is Much Simpler Than You Think

```
var img = $("<img>", {'src':'images/king.png', 'alt':'king' });
$(".item .label").eq(0).append(img);
```

Comment: How is that simpler...? Complexity aside, it's also broken.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  sorry about that. I fixed it.